# How can I ignore all tests in a specific folder using nose?

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, nose, nosetests

I have many unit tests organized in the following manner:

```
test_dir/
  test_important1.py
  test_important2.py
  test_important3.py
  ....
  basic tests/testA1.py
              testA2.py
              ....
              __init__.py
```

I want to run all test in the `test_dir` directory itself, **not including** tests found at `basic tests`.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `--exclude-dir` option introduced by [`nose-exclude`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-exclude):

```
nosetests --exclude-dir="basic tests/"
```